# cómo recorrer y obtener datos en un arreglo multidimensional en PHP

Tags: php, array, objeto

BIen, he estado bloqueado con esto, Cómo obtengo el campo 'id' en este objeto?

```
    object(EntityData)#20 (11) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(11) "entiddad_08"
      ["document_number"]=>
      string(3) "157"
      ["description"]=>
      string(16) "Entidad Prueba 8"
      ["documento"]=>
      string(28) "res/images/default_image.jpg"
      ["user_id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(19) "2021-01-08 17:47:35"
      ["tipo"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["category_id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["empresa"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["active"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "10"
    }
```

/// fraccion del codigo donde saco el registro que me interesa, es a partir de un arreglo de mayor tamaño y saco el registro que me interesa.

```
$all = $entity->getAll($company_id);
foreach($all as $arreglo => $posicion)
{
    //echo "<h1> $producto </h1>";
 
    foreach($posicion as $indice => $valor)
    {
        //echo "<p> $indice:$valor </p>";

        if($indice  == "document_number" && $valor==$datos[0])
        {
            $aux = $posicion;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

He intentado de varias formas como "$aux->EntityData->id;", pero nada, qué es lo más recomendable?

Answer (score 0):

pude acceder de la siguiente manera:

```
$nuevo_arreglo=json_decode(json_encode($aux),true);
```

y luego accediendo al campo id de la siguiente forma:

```
$nuevo_arreglo['id'];
```